# Error en inyeccion de dependencias con jersey, maven y java

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey2

Estoy tratando de crear un servicio *REST* el cual tenga un filtro para cada petición que se realice, este filtro lo que hará es verificar si existe un token, si esto es correcto continuara, caso contrario devolverá un `UNAUTHORIZED`. El problema radica en que intento inyectar una dependencia en mi filtro, pero me da el siguiente error:

```
GRAVE:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=GeneradorDeTokens,parent=JWTTokenNeededFilter,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,270994059)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:294)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:357)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:501)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:220)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:508)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:570)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:562)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:561)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1851)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1727)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:483)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Al parecer la dependencia no puede ser satisfecha. El código que utilizo es el siguiente:

**FILTRO:**

```
@Provider
@JWTokenNeeded
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class JWTTokenNeededFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Inject
    private TokenFactory tokenFactory;


    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        //Obteniendo los encabezados HTTP Authorization de la peticion
        String encabezadosAut = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        //Extrayendo el token de los encabezados HTTP Authorization
        String token = encabezadosAut.substring("Bearer".length()).trim();

        try {
            //Validando el token
            Key key = tokenFactory.generarToken();
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(token);
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException | UnsupportedJwtException | MalformedJwtException | SignatureException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
        }

    }

}
```

**LA CLASE QUE DESEO INYECTAR**

```
import java.security.Key;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

/**
 *
 */
public class GeneradorDeTokens implements TokenFactory{


    @Override
    public Key generarToken(){
        String llave="simplekey";       
        Key key=new SecretKeySpec(llave.getBytes(),0,llave.getBytes().length,"DES");
        return key;
    }
}
```

**LA INTERFAZ UTILIZADA POR LA CLASE**

```
import java.security.Key;

/**
 *
 */
public interface TokenFactory {
    Key generarToken();
}
```

**EL TAG PERSONALIZADO**

```
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;

/**
 *
 */
@NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE,METHOD})
public @interface JWTokenNeeded {

}
```

He seguido un tutorial para la validación y creación de *JWT* , y he quedado atorado en esta parte.

Answer (score 0):

no tengo privilegios para escribir comentarios, pero el problema es posible que lo tengas en que necesitas poner `@Qualifier`. o indicar de alguna forma el bean que quieres que se inyecte.

Mira en la siguiente pregunta de jFrenetic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366589/need-for-injection-qualifier como hace uso del @Qualifier

Creo que deberías anotar la clase que quieres inyectar

```
/**
 *
 */
@JWTokenNeeded
public class GeneradorDeTokens implements TokenFactory{


    @Override
    public Key generarToken(){
        String llave="simplekey";       
        Key key=new     SecretKeySpec(llave.getBytes(),0,llave.getBytes().length,"DES");
        return key;
    }
}
```

y después a la hora de hacer la inyección

```
@Inject @JWTokenNeeded
private TokenFactory tokenFactory;
```

Saludos

Comment: para que la respuesta este completa, es perfectamente válido que traduzcas el contenido de la respuesta en inglés, solo respeta el dejar la mención al autor original y el enlace como referencia; pero insisto es válido que la traduzcas y pongas aquí de modo que sirva a los usuarios en español y de paso te haces de unso puntos